# Does transition work with backdrop-filter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter, css-transitions

CSS `transition` is not working on `backdrop-filter` if I use `overflow:hidden` on parent element.

Example code:

```css
.image-wrapper {
   width: 200px;
   border-radius: 6px;
   position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(0px);
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.image-wrapper:hover .overlay {
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}

.image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<h4>// overflow:hidden (transition not working)</h4>
<div class="image-wrapper" style="overflow: hidden">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/292/536/354.jpg?hmac=JmwZG4JsRmarXfsRwZuzcaOYhm5ZhvdpGAoX6a-syQ0" />
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<h4>// overflow:visible</h4>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/292/536/354.jpg?hmac=JmwZG4JsRmarXfsRwZuzcaOYhm5ZhvdpGAoX6a-syQ0" />
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Example video: https://take.ms/fo80F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real culprit seems to be the `border-radius`.

Sounds like a bug and I couldn't find one (though there are many related since this whole background-filter feature is still full of bugs both in the implementation and the specs), so you might want to report it directly to [the ones that can do something about it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

Note that a workaround is to use a clip-path instead of this border-radius:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0
}
.clip-me {
  clip-path: inset(0px 0px round 6px 6px);
}
  
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(0px);
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.image-wrapper:hover .overlay {
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}

.image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<h4>// overflow:hidden (transition working but overflow is now useless)</h4>
<div class="image-wrapper clip-me" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/292/536/354.jpg?hmac=JmwZG4JsRmarXfsRwZuzcaOYhm5ZhvdpGAoX6a-syQ0" />
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<h4>// overflow:visible</h4>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/292/536/354.jpg?hmac=JmwZG4JsRmarXfsRwZuzcaOYhm5ZhvdpGAoX6a-syQ0" />
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a couple of reasons I would suggest simplifying the code as shown below. I believe it does the same thing you want and is more cross-browser compatible -- as Firefox doesn't currently support `backdrop-filter`.

```css
.image-wrapper {
   width: 200px;
   border-radius: 6px;
   position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  filter: blur(0);
  transition-duration: .5s;
}

.image-wrapper img:hover {
  filter: blur(15px);
}
```

```html
<h4>// overflow:hidden (transition is now working)</h4>
<div class="image-wrapper" style="overflow: hidden">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/292/536/354.jpg?hmac=JmwZG4JsRmarXfsRwZuzcaOYhm5ZhvdpGAoX6a-syQ0" />
</div>

<h4>// overflow:visible</h4>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/292/536/354.jpg?hmac=JmwZG4JsRmarXfsRwZuzcaOYhm5ZhvdpGAoX6a-syQ0" />
</div>
```